# how *return implicitly return a reference

Tags: c++, object, pointers, reference, instances

`this` is a const ptr to the object/instance which a member function receive implicitly, so how does  `return *this` returns a reference ?

As of what I know , a pointer dereferencing to a variable means it holds it's memory address , so `return *this` should return value dereferenced by this const pointer which is what? An object?

Also, why you can't do something like this:

```
Calc cCalc;
cCalc.Add(5).Sub(3).Mult(4);
```

Without having all that member functions to `return *this`?

I would want to know how pointers and reference treat objects/instances.

Comment: `*this` is the object itself, so is the reference that will be returned.

Answer (score 1):

Let's try to untangle:

> this is a const ptr to the object/instance which a member function receive implicitly

member functions indeed receive this pointer implicitly. The type is T* or const T* depending on the member function signature -- you get const placing const keyword at the tail after the ().

> so how does return *this returns a reference ?

*this dereference the pointer, thus creating lvalue of type T or const T respectively. If your question is meant how you get T& from *this in a const funstion, the answer that you don't, that attempt would be ill-formed code.

> As of what I know , a pointer dereferencing to a variable means it holds it's memory address , so return *this should return value dereferenced by this const pointer which is what? An object?

*this denotes the instance. And it is lvalue expression. So you can get its address agan (providing same as this), or can bind it to a reference -- including the case for a return.

The chaining you show can actually be done if the functions returned Calc instead of Calc& or returned some different object than *this -- but then the result of calculations would end up in that place. Not where you expect it: in cCalc.

As it stands, when all three functions return *this leads first Add taking &cCalc in this, and returns cCalc. The next call to Sub has the same situation. And Multiply too.

Answer (score 0):

Add member doesnt have Sub function. Compiler give an error.

But, if you return *this, you are returning **your own object** (not reference). Now you have one cCalc object that can use Sub(3). Sub(3) return your object and can use Mult(4).